# C# error casting an object to a generic interface

Tags: c#, oop, interface, casting

I have the following code. I am unable to cast the object of ISearchProvider to another interface which the class has implemented.

```
public interface IGenericSearchProcessor<T> where T: ISearchCriteria
{
    Task<ISearchResponse> Search(T criteria);
}

public class GibsonSearchProvider : IGenericSearchProcessor<ISearchCriteria>, IAggregateSearch, ISearchProvider
{

  public async Task<ISearchResponse> Search(ISearchCriteria criteria)
  {
    return new BasicSearchResponse
    {
        AggregateResults = aggregates
    };
  } 
}

public class GenericSearchStrategy<T> : ISearchStrategy<T> where T : ISearchCriteria
{
    public Task<ISearchResponse> Search(ISearchProvider provider, T criteria)
    {
        //exception here when try to cast.      
        var p = (IGenericSearchProcessor<T>)provider;


        //return ((IGenericSearchProcessor<T>)provider).Search(criteria);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. If the cast fails, then presumably the provider doesn't *actually* implement the interface you're casting to...

Comment: it is implementing. i have edited the code

Comment: If you want an `IGenericSearchProcessor<T>` then you should be *accepting that as your parameter*, rather than an `ISearchProvider` that you just hope also implements that interface.

Comment: You still haven't provided a [mcve] though. We can't see what you're calling `Search` with. I'm afraid without being able to reproduce the problem, I still believe it's more likely that there's a problem with your code than with the runtime. I suggest you use a debugger to break just before the cast, and check what `T` and `provider` are, in detail.

Comment: GibsonSearchProvider class implements the IGenericSearchProcessor<ISearchCriteria>. my question is whether this provider could be casted to this generic interface because it has implemented it?

Comment: when i try provider.GetType().GetInterfaces(); it gives me the generic interface along with othe interface

Answer (score 0):

That cast would only work if:

1. The object passed to your `Search` method is of a type that implements `IGenericSearchProcessor<T>` and,
2. `IGenericSearchProcessor<T>` implements `ISearchProvider`. Your code shows that `IGenericSearchProcessor<T>` implements `ISearchCriteria`, not `ISearchProvider`.

If you are just going to cast the parameter to `IGenericSearchProcessor<T>`, then I would suggest just making that the type of the parameter:

```
public Task<ISearchResponse> Search(IGenericSearchProcessor<T> provider, T criteria) {
    ...
}
```

Just doing that will likely show where your other code could be going wrong.